# How do you generate mud plots for planting mushrooms?

Tags: gnomoria

With the latest patch, the game introduced mushrooms to grow them underground. This special plant can only grow underground and on mud plots.

**How do you generate those mud plots?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mud plots are generated by flooding a room that is adjacent to water as shown in the screenshot below. There is also no sunlight to be allowed to shine on the mushrooms.

At the moment there is no other way to generate those plots for the mushrooms.

[image: Mud plots]

Comment: The problem with flooding is the water doesn't move that far, so you need to build your farm right next to the water supply. I have a farm I want further away from a water source, and tried to build a tunnel and channel water down to it, but that doesn't work very well. My current solution is to dig up the floor above it so it gets rained on, and am replacing the floor as the soil below gets wet. Very slow going and patchy, but it seems to be working OK for now.

Comment: @Rachel That complete room was flooded, except for the purple tiles.

Comment: @Rachel "The problem with flooding" is that barely nudging a body of water will result in a flood that would make Noah impressed..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific place you want a mushroom farm, you could also strip the floor above on a 2x2 box and wait for it to fill with water - extend that out to 3x3 and so on, extending only one axis (3x4, 3x5, etc). Once your area is sufficiently large enough, drop a floor on it (all but 3 spaces so the water is replenished) and tunnel underneath for your farm. Repeat as required:).

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a rain pool, it looks ugly but it works.

- Ramp down a 7x7 on level 0.
- Ramp down a 5x5 on level -1 in the unramped square.
- Ramp down a 3x3 on level -2 in the unramped square.
- Ramp down a 1x1 on level -3 in the unramped square.
- Dig hole on the ramp on level -4.
- Mine a 3x3 room with the middle tile under the rain pool

Designate it as an underground farm you will have a 8 tile farm.
The rain will flow down the ramp to the farm, you could make it from the 3x3 step on level 0 but rain is randomly generated and it could happen that no rain will fall into your rain pool.

I noticed by excavating that with an enough deep ramp you can create a new pool of water, so I tried it with mushrooms both work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Noneofyourbusiness had stated it is a matter of putting water and letting it dry up to become mud.

The way I did it was one level *below* the water supply.  I created a large enough plot of empty land which should hopefully absorb and distribute the water.

On the level with the water bottom of the water supply I create a 3X3 area with a hole in the middle.  When all is ready I just cut the hole to the water supply and funnel it down to the bottom level.

This will totally empty the lake rendering it practically useless since after 11 years rain won't even come close to filling it up. The only thing useful thing that it can be converted to may be a lava moat, though I haven't gone that far yet.